# 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Okay, I have a bit of a weird bug...

This works fine:

```
private void radioButtonNormalPoint_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //comboBoxNormalPoint.SelectedIndex = 0;
   //ellipsePoint.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
}
```

This throws `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`:

```
private void radioButtonNormalPoint_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBoxNormalPoint.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ellipsePoint.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
}
```

Also, it doesn't let me debug it; it crashes as the program loads. If I put a breakpoint anywhere it doesn't hit it; it just errors right away.

Comment: Document the InnerException and stack trace.

Comment: You have to comment out both lines, right? Or does the crash happen only with the first line? SelectedINdex=0.

Comment: It's any lines (doesn't matter even if i just declare a variable int i = 0;) And the Inner Exception is null but in the unhandled exception thing that pops up (since i can't catch it) it says Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: It might be the event handler hookup. Show me where you hook the event. If possible, do it in the code-behnd

Comment: <RadioButton Content="Normal Point:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,143,0,0" Name="radioButtonNormalPoint" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" IsChecked="True" GroupName="a" Checked="radioButtonNormalPoint_Checked" />

Comment: 2 years late, but on a related note I find it extremely in cases like this to break when an exception is thrown. ie. DEBUG>Exceptions> "Break when an exception is:"> Thrown (for Common Language Runtime Exceptions)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The event is probably raised before the elements are fully loaded or the references are still unset, hence the exceptions. Try only setting properties if the reference is not `null` and `IsLoaded` is `true`.

Comment: The error was caused because the radio button is checked already when it loads and it tries to assign a value to the combobox.selectedindex which hasn't loaded yet

Comment: @JustinKirk: Just as i expected :)

Comment: In my case I had copy and pasted a textbox with a function triggering on TextChanged referring to itself. I forgot to change the target of the function for the second box so it died finding the other textbox was still null.

Answer (score 6):

To diagnose this issue, place the line of code causing the TargetInvocationException inside the try block.

To troubleshoot this type of error, get the inner exception.  It could be due to a number of different issues.

```
try
{
    // code causing TargetInvocationException
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
    string err = e.InnerException.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have fewer problems if you declared a Property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, then databind `IsChecked`, `SelectedIndex`(using IValueConverter) and `Fill`(using IValueConverter) to it instead of using the Checked Event to toggle `SelectedIndex` and `Fill`.

Answer (score 0):

If the radiobutton-checked event occurs before the content of the window is loaded fully, i.e. the ellipse is loaded fully, such an exception will be thrown. So check if the UI of the window is loaded (probably by Window_ContentRendered event, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by an attempt to process a null object.
An example, trying to empty a Bindable list that is null will trigger the exception:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    [BindableProperty]
    public virtual IList<Products> ProductsList{ get; set; }

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        ProductsList.Clear(); // here is the problem
    }
}
```

This could easily be fixed by checking for null:

```
if (ProductsList!= null) ProductsList.Clear();
```