# C# and WPF - 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on a wpf application with visual studio 2012.  The program had been starting up just fine until now.  I had just finished adding a decent amount of code, and I hadn't started the program in a while.  When I attempted to, I got a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.
I tried to step into the code, but I got the message "PresentationFramework.pdb not loaded".

I tried 'Start without debugging'.  This time I got no exception, but it just didn't do anything.  I have tried commenting out portions of my code to find the problem points, but I made no progress.

The code I had just added had nothing to do with wpf, if that has anything to with it.

Comment: Did you do a "Rebuild Solution"?

Comment: Dude, look at the inner exception.

Comment: I guess it is a problem in some markup code (XAML)

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164488/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-occurred-in-presentationframework There's not enough information in this post though.. Have you searched for answers, and if you did, which ones didn't work?

Comment: @Patrick, I have searched, but I found nothing but that link, which didn't help much.  And yes I have rebuilt the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your xaml code is correct and clear all syntax at

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start debugging from `Window.Initialized` event

```c#
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int a; //put breakpoint here
}
```

XAML code:

```c#
<Window x:Class="ProjectName.MainWindow" ... Initialized="Window_Initialized">
```